# C# WPF Iterate through ListView items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

I've been going nuts trying to find a solution to what seems like a simple problem. I am trying to find a way to Iterate through my ListView and get values.

I have a ListView with bindings which looks like this in xaml (simplified):

```
<ListView x:Name="MColumnsListXaml" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="0,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MColumnName}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MColumnName2}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I declare bindings:

```
public class MandatoryColumns
{
    public string MColumnName { get; set; }
    public string MColumnName2 { get; set; }
}
```

Columns are populated by an event trigger which calls a method:

```
private void btnValidateColumns_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MandatoryOptionalColumnsList();
}
public void MandatoryOptionalColumnsList()
{
    List<MandatoryColumns> MColumnsList = new List<MandatoryColumns>();
    MColumnsList.Add(new MandatoryColumns() { MColumnName = "John", MColumnName2 = "Smith" });
    MColumnsList.Add(new MandatoryColumns() { MColumnName = "Jason", MColumnName2 = "Bell" });
    MColumnsListXaml.ItemsSource = MColumnsList;
}
```

Now I need to get information that is in the ListView and that's where I'm stuck. My intention is to extract a column in a ListView and cross check against another list. To get the values, I've tried `foreach` loop as per below:

```
public void test()
{
    foreach (var item in MColumnsListXaml.Items)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(MColumnsListXaml.ToString()); //MColumnsListXaml = {System.Windows.Controls.ListView Items.Count:2}
        MessageBox.Show(MColumnsListXaml.Items.ToString()); //MColumnsListXaml.Items = {System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection}
        MessageBox.Show(item.ToString()); //item = {tutorialWpfApplication1.MandatoryColumns}
    }
}
```

In debugger I see item returns object `{tutorialWpfApplication1.MandatoryColumns}` and holds my [needed information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnkfn.png), but I can't find a way to access it. I tried to iterate `item` by making it `dynamic`, declare `ListViewItem` instead of `var and various solutions online, but everything always resulted in an exception error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you set the value of `ItemsSource` you also can get the value. So you can cast and use the list like

```
List<MandatoryColumns> items = (List<MandatoryColumns>)MColumnsListXaml.ItemsSource;
foreach (MandatoryColumns item in items)
{
    //Do some work with the MandatoryColumns item
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, but it has exactly same outcome. Item returns `{tutorialWpfApplication1.MandatoryColumns}` just like i have it in screenshot in my post. I can see this information in `item` object in my debugger, but dont know how to access it.

Comment: I was too early to answer. I now actually can access the value. I can't believe it was so simple!

Comment: Don't forget to give the guy the "Correct answer" vote if he answered your question.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
foreach (var item in MColumnsListXaml.Items.OfType<MandatoryColumns>())
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.MColumnName);
    MessageBox.Show(item.MColumnName2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cast `item` to the type `MandatoryColumn` you should be able access the values. As long as you know that every item in the list is of that type then you shouldn't get an exception when casting.